# Can I insert a file into Excel without creating a reference?

Tags: excel, pdf, reference, embed, share

Is there a way to insert a pdf file into Excel such that when I send the excel to another PC, they can still open the pdf file?

To do this I understand that I can't create a reference to the file because that file is saved on my computer but not on the other person's computer. What I need is to embed the file, correct? How can I do this without using a reference to an object, like a link? Again, what I want is this file put directly into my Excel.

Is this even possible? Would it maybe work on an excel that has sharing enabled so multiple users can access the excel at once?

If it helps, I ask because I'm creating a program that automatically creates files and needs to somehow connect them to this shared excel.

Comment: You can easily embed a PDF into a worksheet without linking it to the source file. Just use the Insert - Object button, then choose Create from file, and make sure the link to file option is unchecked.

Comment: @Rory can't believe it was that simple. Just to be clear, this file will work on any pc, right? Thanks!

Comment: Yes - the actual file is embedded within the workbook structure.